# Relatorio Sub-total por Grupo com PHP

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, bootstrap-4

Pretendo exibir o resultado do relatório mais ou menos dessa forma:

| Indústria | Comissão | Valor Comissão | Nº Prestação | Vencimento | Valor Pedido | Nº Pedido |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *123456780* | 1 % | R$ 8,24 | 1 | 2021-09-16 | R$ 823,91 | 21 |
| *123456780* | 1 % | R$ 31,25 | 1 | 2021-09-25 | R$ 3.125,00 | 23 |
| Subtotal |  | R$ 39,49 |  |  |  |  |
| *876543210* | 7 % | R$ 42,14 | 1 | 2021-09-25 | R$ 601,96 | 19 |
| Subtotal |  | R$ 42,14 |  |  |  |  |
| Total |  | R$ 81,63 |  |  |  |  |

**Essa tabela acima é o resultado final que espero alcançar.**

---

Minha tabela até o momento está dessa assim:

| Indústria | Comissão | Valor Comissão | Nº Prestação | Vencimento | Valor Pedido | Nº Pedido |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456780 | 1 % | R$ 8,24 | 1 | 2021-09-16 | R$ 823,91 | 21 |
| 123456780 | 1 % | R$ 31,25 | 1 | 2021-09-25 | R$ 3.125,00 | 23 |
| 876543210 | 7 % | R$ 42,14 | 1 | 2021-09-25 | R$ 601,96 | 19 |
| Total |  | R$ 81,63 |  |  |  |  |

**Agora o meu código:**

***MySQLi:***

```
SELECT f.industria, i.comissao, f.numero_prestacao, f.vencimento, f.valor_pedido, f.numero_pedido FROM adms_financeiros f INNER JOIN adms_industrias i ON f.adms_industria_cgc=i.cgc WHERE f.vencimento BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-30 23:59:59'
```

***HTML e PHP:***

```
$query = "SELECT f.industria, i.comissao, f.numero_prestacao, f.vencimento, f.valor_pedido, f.numero_pedido FROM adms_financeiros f INNER JOIN adms_industrias i ON f.adms_industria_cgc=i.cgc WHERE f.vencimento BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-30 23:59:59'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabela_com_pesquisa" style="width:98%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Indústria</th>
                            <th>Comissão</th>
                            <th>Valor Comissão</th>
                            <th>Nº Prestação</th>
                            <th>Vencimento</th>
                            <th>Valor Pedido</th>
                            <th>Nº Pedido</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>';
                    
                    if (($result) and ($result->num_rows != 0)) {
                        echo "<tbody>";
                        $total = 0;
                        
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            extract($row);
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$adms_industria_cgc</td>";
                            echo "<td>".($comissao * 100)." %</td>";
                            $valor_comissao = $valor * $comissao;
                            echo "<td>R$ ".number_format($valor_comissao,2,',','.')."</td>";
                            echo "<td>$numero_prestacao</td>";
                            echo "<td>$vencimento</td>";
                            echo "<td>R$ ".number_format($valor,2,',','.')."</td>";
                            echo "<td>$adms_pedido_id</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            $total = $valor_comissao + $total;
                        }
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>Total</td><td>R$ ".number_format($total,2,',','.')."</td></tr>";

                        echo "</tbody>";
                        echo "</table>";
                    }
                echo '</div>';
```

Como posso adicionar os Subtotais?

### EDIT:

Com a ajuda do Marcus Italo consegui chegar nesse resultado abaixo:

| Indústria | Comissão | Valor Comissão | Nº Prestação | Vencimento | Valor Pedido | Nº Pedido |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456780 | 1 % | R$ 8,24 | 1 | 2021-09-16 | R$ 823,91 | 21 |
| 123456780 | 1 % | R$ 31,25 | 1 | 2021-09-25 | R$ 3.125,00 | 23 |
| 876543210 | 7 % | R$ 42,14 | 1 | 2021-09-25 | R$ 601,96 | 19 |
| Subtotal |  | R$ 39,49 |  |  |  |  |
| Total |  | R$ 81,63 |  |  |  |  |

Com esse código abaixo:

```
if (($result) and ($result->num_rows != 0)) {
                    echo "<tbody>";
                    $total = 0;
                    $subtot = 0;
                    $grupo = '12345678000132';
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        extract($row);
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$adms_industria_cgc</td>";
                        echo "<td>".($comissao * 100)." %</td>";
                        $valor_comissao = $valor * $comissao;
                        echo "<td>R$ ".number_format($valor_comissao,2,',','.')."</td>";
                        echo "<td>$numero_prestacao</td>";
                        echo "<td>$vencimento</td>";
                        echo "<td>R$ ".number_format($valor,2,',','.')."</td>";
                        echo "<td>$adms_pedido_id</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $total = $valor_comissao + $total;
                        if ($grupo == $adms_industria_cgc) {
                            $subtot = $valor_comissao + $subtot;
                            $grupo = $adms_industria_cgc;
                        }else{
                            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>SubTotal</td><td>R$ ".number_format($subtotal,2,',','.')."</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
                        }
                        $subtotal = $subtot;
                        
                    }
                    echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td></td><td>R$ ".number_format($total,2,',','.')."</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
                    echo "</tbody>";
                    echo "</table>";
                }
```

Como posso imprimir a linha Subtotal -> R$ 39,49 após a indústria 123456780? E depois ainda adicionar mais uma linha de Subtotal -> R$ 42,14 após a indústria 876543210?

Comment: Olá, Diulius. Você precisará de algum campo que identifique o grupo de dados que você quer unir. Com isso, você poderá implementar algo semelhante a $total. Fora do loop você terá duas variável de controle. Ex: $grupo,$subtotal=0, na primeira interação dentro o while, Irá atribuir o valor ao $grupo e o valor a $subtotal, fará um if posterior para saber se o valor de $grupo mudou, se o valor do grupo for o mesmo vai continuar somando em $subtotal, se o $grupo mudar aplica as tags html com o valor de $subtotal, atribua o novo valor a $grupo, e recomece os valores de $subtotal.

Comment: @MarcusItalo Obrigado pelas dicas estou chegando bem próximo do esperado.  Porém ainda não estou conseguindo separar o grupo (que no caso é a indústria). Tem mais alguma dica de como separar ou um exemplo?  Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Diuluis, você poderá fazer algo assim. Verifique se isso dá certo para você.
Explicação, na primeira interação você só adicionará qual grupo/indústria você irá começar a contabilizar, quando houver a troca de grupo/indústria será impresso na tela o subtotal acumulado. após isso será setado o novo grupo e o subtotal zerado para iniciar a contagem do valor do novo grupo. espero ter ajudado.

```
if (($result) and ($result->num_rows != 0)) {
    echo "<tbody>";
    $total = 0;
    $subtotal = 0;
    $grupo = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        extract($row);                          
        if($grupo == 0){
            $grupo = $adms_industria_cgc;
        }                       
        if($grupo != $adms_industria_cgc){
            echo "<tr><td>SubTotal</td><td></td><td>R$ ".number_format($subtotal,2,',','.')."</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
            $grupo = $adms_industria_cgc;
            $subtotal = 0;
        }                       
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$adms_industria_cgc</td>";
        echo "<td>".($comissao * 100)." %</td>";
        $valor_comissao = $valor * $comissao;
        echo "<td>R$ ".number_format($valor_comissao,2,',','.')."</td>";
        echo "<td>$numero_prestacao</td>";
        echo "<td>$vencimento</td>";
        echo "<td>R$ ".number_format($valor,2,',','.')."</td>";
        echo "<td>$adms_pedido_id</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $total = $valor_comissao + $total;
        $subtotal = $valor_comissao + $subtotal;                        
    }
    echo "<tr><td>SubTotal</td><td></td><td>R$ ".number_format($subtotal,2,',','.')."</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td></td><td>R$ ".number_format($total,2,',','.')."</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não deu certo ainda está retornando do mesmo jeito que a ultima tabela.